# Hide Nebular stepper navigation

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to hide the Nebular stepper navigation display with no luck.
I tried to set display: none on the header class but didn't work. I don't want to have to copy over the source and modify or even extend the component for a small change.

[image]

Comment: Adding relevant code, or better yet, creating a demo on stackblitz (nebular seed: https://stackblitz.com/github/akveo/nebular-seed) really helps resolve problems! You're far more likely to get accurate responses if you do this for us folks trying to help. In the mean time, try appending `hidden=true` to the HTML element you want to hide.

Answer (score 2):

With some help from Artem, I was able to solve the problem with the following:

```
:host ::ng-deep nb-stepper .header {
  display: none;
}
```